# Remove lines partially matching other lines in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following lines in **input.txt**:

```
    client_citic_plat_fix44;CITICHK;interbridge_ulnet_se_eqx
    client_citic_plat_fix44;CITICHK;interbridge_ulnet_se_eqx;CITICHK;interbridge_hk_eqx
    client_dkp_crd;DELIVERTOCOMPID;DESTINATION
    client_dkp_crd;NORD;interbridge_fr
    client_dkp_crd;NORD;interbridge_fr;broker_nordea_2
    client_dkp_crd;AVIA;interbridge_fr
    client_dkp_crd;AVIA;interbridge_fr;interbridge_ld
    client_dkp_crd;SEBAP;interbridge_fr
    client_dkp_crd;SEBAP;interbridge_fr;broker_seb_ss_thl
    client_epf_crd;DELIVERTOCOMPID;DESTINATION
```

I need some bash  (awk/sed) script to remove the lines that are partially similar to others. Desired output should be:

```
    client_citic_plat_fix44;CITICHK;interbridge_ulnet_se_eqx;CITICHK;interbridge_hk_eqx
    client_dkp_crd;DELIVERTOCOMPID;DESTINATION
    client_dkp_crd;NORD;interbridge_fr;broker_nordea_2
    client_dkp_crd;AVIA;interbridge_fr;interbridge_ld
    client_dkp_crd;SEBAP;interbridge_fr;broker_seb_ss_thl
    client_epf_crd;DELIVERTOCOMPID;DESTINATION
```

Columns 1, 2 and 3 are always similar and I always want to remove the shortest line between the two compared.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a question, it's simply a code request. Please read [ask].

Comment: @TomFenech Apparently code requests are allowed as long as the answer is helpful to someone. That's why there is no close reason for it.

Comment: Guys this is not a code request but rather about how to check if a line is PARTIALLY matching another one. General ideas about how I can do that would be enough.

Comment: Are the similar lines always together? Are they always lines n and n+1, or can they be lines n+1 and n+2?

Comment: What constitutes partially, 1 letter, 10 letters ? Here's an idea, look up basic awk and sed commands, have a go at solving and come back with your attempt.

Comment: @Beta First three columns are always the identical part of both lines that are to be compared. Columns are always separated by ';'. There can be n+1 and n+2 lines as well. Thanks!

Comment: @User112638726  I used: 
    awk -F ';' 'NF>=4'
but I was looking for something which really does a compare between lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `grep` and `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filepath"
while IFS= read -r line;do
 (($(grep $line "$file" -c)>1)) && sed -i "/^$line$/d" "$file"
done <"$file"
```

Note: This will replace your file.

To not replace your file and to put the output to another file, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
infile="infilepath"
outfile="outfilepath"
cp "$infile" "$outfile"
while IFS= read -r line;do
 (($(grep $line "$infile" -c)>1)) && sed -i "/^$line$/d" "$outfile"
done <"$infile"
```